# Assigning return function to another variable (this)

Tags: javascript, html, variables, return, this

JS:

```
function selectPeg(element) {
    var id = element.id;
    var color = document.getElementById(id).getAttribute("data-color");
    return color;
}

var v = selectPeg(this);
console.log(v);
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div id="selectpeg1" onclick="selectPeg(this)" data-color="yellow"></div></td>
        <td><div id="selectpeg2" onclick="selectPeg(this)" data-color="blue"></div></td>
        <td><div id="selectpeg3" onclick="selectPeg(this)" data-color="red"></div></td>
        <td><div id="selectpeg4" onclick="selectPeg(this)" data-color="green"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to pass the "color" returned by selectPeg(...) function to another variable, but this seems to give me different errors when I play around with the code. Anyone knows how to put the return color into "v" variable?

Comment: Try instead with `var v = selectPeg(document.getElementById('selectpeg1'));`. – The value of `this` can change based on where it's used. Outside of the `onclick` attributes, it won't automatically refer to any of the `<div>` elements.

Comment: Yeah, but I want the function to return the color depending on which div is clicked. Not just return the color of the first peg

Comment: The events will provide you with each element as the user interacts with them. You'll want to call the other function within the handler rather than globally. `onclick="yourOtherFunction(selectPeg(this))"`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function selectPeg(element) {
var v = element.getAttribute("data-color");
console.log(v);
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div id="selectpeg1" onclick="selectPeg(this)" data-color="yellow">yellow</div></td>
        <td><div id="selectpeg2" onclick="selectPeg(this)" data-color="blue">blue</div></td>
        <td><div id="selectpeg3" onclick="selectPeg(this)" data-color="red">red</div></td>
        <td><div id="selectpeg4" onclick="selectPeg(this)" data-color="green">green</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `var v = selectPeg(this);` would cause you error if you are calling it from global scope. The reason is that value of `this` would be window and inside `selectPeg` function, `element.id` would give value undefined.

You can call `selectPeg` by first selecting the element.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('selectpeg1');
```

Then call

```
var v = selectPeg(elem);
```

Also note that the call `document.getElementById(id)` is not required inside function `selectPeg`.
So in case of click event also, you would get the element and no need to again get the id and call `getElementById`.

If you want color value then you can declare the variable outside the function and populate it inside the function like this:

```js
var v;

function selectPeg(element) {
  //var id = element.id;
  //var color = document.getElementById(id).getAttribute("data-color");
  var color = element.getAttribute("data-color");
  v = color;

}

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  console.log(v);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="selectpeg1" onclick="selectPeg(this)" data-color="yellow">1</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="selectpeg2" onclick="selectPeg(this)" data-color="blue">2</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="selectpeg3" onclick="selectPeg(this)" data-color="red">3</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="selectpeg4" onclick="selectPeg(this)" data-color="green">4</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="btn">getV</button>
```

So in the code, you click and store the value in v and then get the value after clicking the button `getV`.

Comment: alright, but I want the user to click the div with a certain colour and then pass it to the variable "v".

Comment: See my edited solution. I created a button on the click of which you would get color that is stored in v.

Comment: The whole problem is when you return the color in the function (return color;). And try to assign that function to the external variable depending on the div that was clicked. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @szubansky When you click and return from the click handler function, you would never get to the line `var v = selectPeg(this);` because this line didn't call your event handler. If you want to reach there then you have to call your function from that place as I showed you earlier.

Comment: Okay, is there any way to do in with the if statement? So if selectpeg1 is clicked, the function returns yellow, in case of selectpeg2, it gives blue etc. I am using this function to get 4 guesses of colours form the user and then compare it with computer generated colors so I need to compare somehow

Comment: So you want to compare each time a color is clicked? Where is computer generated color coming from? Do you already have them in an array or so?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/FWAyQxEg
Here is the code to my game, I want to replace the prompt with the input from HTML. So I click the div, compare the color with the computer-generated one, then click the second div, again compare it and so on

Comment: @szubansky When is play() called? Who calls?

Comment: I will have a button to call play and start the game, I haven't figured it out yet. Right now I'm just trying to get the input and comparisons right

Comment: @szubansky And by the time play() is called, the user would have clicked 4 times?

Comment: Actually, he has to click four times in each of 10 rounds until he gets the right combination or the run out of tries (Im gonna put it inside do while loop)
So its gonna be like:
Select four colors by clicking on a colored pegs
I compare those 4 clicks with the generated combination
If its incorrect I move to the next round (next row) , wait for 4 clicks and compare again

Comment: @szubansky Can you refine the problem clearly in the question itself? Looks like there is more to it as we are discussing!

Comment: Alright, so I need a function that depending on a clicked div will return it's attribute as a string (color). Then I want to assign that string to a variable. Compare this variable with the first color generated by computer. Click again on a different div, update that variable and again compare it with the next color generated by the computer. Is that clear? :D

Comment: @szubansky In that case, once a color is selected inside `selectPeg`, instead of `return`, you call a function say compare(color) by passing the color. Let's say the color is 'yellow'. Now inside compare() body, make a call to some function that would give you a randomly generated color. Once obtained, now compare 'yellow' with a random color.

Comment: Yea, but that would move the gameplay from play to selectPeg